# Add collection in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created a contenitor collection that is a by-pass for another collection. Inside this once (contenitor) I fetch another collection and I want add the fetch results inside the first one contenitor collection.I know exists options add:true but seems not works.

```
var Contenitor = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  twitterQuery:undefined,
  page: undefined,
  initialize: function () {
    this.TweetsCollection = new Tweets();   
  },  
  fetch: function() {
    this.TweetsCollection.query=this.twitterQuery;
    this.TweetsCollection.page=this.page;
    this.TweetsCollection.fetch({
      success:function (tweets){
        this.add(tweets);<---here nothing is added to this collection
      }
   });
 },
});
```

and this is the fetch of TWeetsCollection:

```
fetch: function(options) {

var collection = this; 
var params = {
user_id: this.query,
//screen_name:"brad"
page:this.page
};


cb.__call(
"statuses_userTimeline",
params,
function (reply) {
// console.log(reply);
  collection.reset(reply);

}
 );
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you trying to set the data from the TweetsCollection.fetch() call to the Contenitor collection on success?

Comment: The comma on the last brace is correct? :P

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is the "this"-scope, which doesn't refer to anything. [Backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) informs that this indeed is an asyncronous function, so you have to give success-callback something to refer to when it is called. You could do this:

```
var self = this;
---
this.TweetsCollection.fetch({
    success: function (tweets) {
        self.add(tweets);
    }    
});
```

Now self refers to caller of inner function.

Comment: Does the success-callback's tweets-parameter contain anything?

Comment: I've added tweets collection fetch below. I think depends on collection.reset but I've changed with return reply and doesn't work

Comment: and success callback is never called but tweetsCollection fetch correctly

Comment: Error and success function haven't never called, but if I console.log tweetscollection after fetch is correctly populated